# equivalence on prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to show that if $ n!+1$ is prime then (n+1)! +1 is  not prime .
My idea is that if $n!+1$ is prime
$ (n!)!\equiv -1[n!+1]$
$ n!(n!-1)..(n+1)!\equiv -1[n!+1]$
$ (-2)(-3)...(n+1)!\equiv 1[n!+1]$
i have a problem to conclude. Could you help please  ?

Comment: According to the notes to OEIS A002981, whether or not this holds for $n>2$ is a conjecture.

Comment: It is open whether this is true for every sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this idea helps:

$$n!+1=p$$

$$N=(n+1)!+1=(n+1)n!+1=n\cdot n!+n!+1=n(p-1)+p \Rightarrow N\equiv p \bmod (p-1)$$

We compare this with following congruence:

$$p^{\phi(p-1)}\equiv 1\bmod (p-1)\Rightarrow p^{\phi(p-1)+1}\equiv p \bmod (p-1)$$

We may conclude that:

$N\equiv p^{\phi(p-1)+1}$

that is $N=(n+1)!+1$ is not prime.